# Siunitx's Scientific Notation doesn't like huge numbers?

Tags: siunitx

In the following MWE we have a `\num` command in the first line. It is printed as it should. But when I add `[scientific-notation=true]` like I saw in the manual, but it gave me an error and replaced the number I typed for another that I'll put in bold. I'm looking for a workaround (while I'd like to keep using siunitx, if possible, but I'll accept other packages if they're compatible).

---------- MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    This is a big number \num{4000000000000}.

    In scientific notation... \num[scientific-notation=true]{4000000000000}
\end{document}
```

---------- ERROR

l.9 ...um[scientific-notation=true]{4000000000000}

**I can only go up to 2147483647='17777777777="7FFFFFFF,
so I'm using that number instead of yours.**

! Number too big.
 4000000000
                     000-10*\l__siunitx_tmp_int 
l.9 ...um[scientific-notation=true]{4000000000000}

I can only go up to 2147483647='17777777777="7FFFFFFF,
so I'm using that number instead of yours.

Comment: Which version of the `siunitx` package do you have on your system? I have version `2016/01/19 v2.6p` on mine, and I'm not able to replicate the error you're reporting.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (GNOME). I don't know how I can check that information for you, but it is what it was available with a fresh install or with the package manager. I only did a manual installation of Texmaker 4.5.

Comment: You could look in the log file - search for the string `Package: siunitx`.

Comment: Package: siunitx 2013/07/31 v2.5s A comprehensive (SI) units package

Comment: Related: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373) -- Linux distributions' TeX packages tend to be quite out of date, since a given release like 14.04 will only get security updates after a while (and most all TeX updates aren't security-related). Even a bleeding-edge distribution like Debian unstable will just get a snapshot of TeX packages periodically.

Comment: I'm afraid your copy of `siunitx` is badly out of date. Do try to (a) download the file `siunitx.dtx` from `http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx` and (b) run LaTeX on the dtx file. Doing so should extract the file `siunitx.sty` *and* create the highly readable user guide, `siunitx.pdf`.

Comment: Downloaded it and extracted to a folder. Now whenever I try to compile it (tried LaTex/PDFLaTeX/...) it gives me errors. Usually "Log file not found". Is there another way to update my packages on Linux? Because I'd like to update everything that has an update available...

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas - Aah, I now recall that `siunitx` depends on the `l3*` packages, which of course have also been updated significantly since July 2013. I'm afraid I'm not an Ubuntu specialist, so I can't tell you how you may wish to proceed. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been solved in some version of siunitx between yours and the current version. Tested your MWE on Ubuntu 14.04, TeXLive 2015, siunitx 2.6p. No errors.

You just need to update your LaTeX installation.

My recommendation is to remove the Ubuntu LaTeX packages from your system completely. They are horribly outdated anyway and won't be updated. Something along the lines of:

`apt-get remove texlive-base`

Then [download and install TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and from there on use the utility `tlmgr` to update or add LaTeX packages on your system. [Just follow the instructions from this SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373). You should be up and running in no time (but note that downloading the full LaTeX repo may still take a while :-)